# Build up two linked list, then build up a 3rd link list with nodes of duplicate data from both

Tags: c++, linked-list, comparative-review

A friend of mines needed some help. He wanted to build up two linked list and then compared them to see if they had the same data values. Finally a 3rd link list would contain the nodes with duplicated data. The linked list holds int data btw. I redid his code and I was aiming to be as simple and clean as possible but I have a shaky feeling. Below is my code and his code together. I feel there is something to learn from both of us so I posted both of our codes although my solution is fully finished. Is my code simple and clean? Is my friend's code formatted in such a way that my code is missing it? Does my look good on the eyes. Critique on both solution would help me grow a bit.

Laurent's code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

struct Node{
    Node* next;
    int data;
};

class LinkedList{
private:
    int length;
    Node* head;
public:
    LinkedList();
    ~LinkedList();
    Node* getHead();
    void appendToTail(int data);
    void appendExistingNodesToTail(Node* newtail, int data); //Takes a collection of node pointers. This is used to append existing nodes from other lists to it own list. 
    void insertToHead(int data);
    void print();
};
LinkedList::LinkedList(){
    this->length = 0;
    this->head = NULL;
}
LinkedList::~LinkedList(){  
    //avoid memory leaks.... give back what you take
    Node* next = head;
    Node* cur = NULL;
    while (next != NULL) {
        cur = next;
        next = next->next;
        delete cur;
    }
    cout << "LIST DELETED"<< endl;
}
Node* LinkedList::getHead(){
    return head;
}
void LinkedList::appendToTail(int data){
    Node *newtail = new Node;
    newtail->data = data;
    newtail->next = nullptr;

    if (this->head == nullptr) {
        head = newtail;
    } 
    else {
        Node *temp = head;
        while (temp->next != nullptr) {
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        temp->next = newtail;
        this->length++;
    }
}
void LinkedList::appendExistingNodesToTail(Node* newtail, int data){
    newtail = new Node;
    newtail->data = data;
    newtail->next = nullptr;

    if (this->head == nullptr) {
        head = newtail;
    } 
    else {
        Node *temp = head;
        while (temp->next != nullptr) {
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        temp->next = newtail;
        this->length++;
    }
}
void LinkedList::insertToHead(int data){
    Node* newhead = new Node;
    newhead->data = data; 
    newhead->next = this->head; 
    this->head = newhead;
    this->length++;
}
void LinkedList::print(){
    Node* head = this->head;
    int i = 1;
    while(head){
        std::cout << i << ": " << head->data << std::endl;
        head = head->next;
        i++;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
//-------------------------------------GENERAL PURPOSE FUNCTIONS------------------------------------------//
void generateDuplicateNodeDataFound(LinkedList* list_a, LinkedList* list_b, LinkedList* list_c){ //Find the duplicate values to build up list c from existing nodes from list a&b. Need two list to compare, one list to build
    Node* head1 = list_a->getHead();
    Node* head2 = list_b->getHead();

    while(head1){
        while(head2){
            if (head1->data == head2->data){
                list_c->appendExistingNodesToTail(head1, head1->data);
                break;
            }
            head2 = head2->next;        
        }
        head1 = head1->next;
        head2 = list_b->getHead(); // Reset
    }
}
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]){

    LinkedList* list1 = new LinkedList();
    LinkedList* list2 = new LinkedList();
    LinkedList* list_found_duplicates = new LinkedList(); 

    int arr1[] = {2,5,7,9,0,2};
    int arr2[] = {9,78,3,2,5,9};

    //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37538/how-do-i-determine-the-size-of-my-array-in-c
    int lenght = sizeof(arr1) / sizeof(arr1[0]);
    for(int i=0; i<lenght; i++){
        list1->appendToTail(arr1[i]);
    }
    lenght = sizeof(arr2) / sizeof(arr2[0]);
    for(int i=0; i<lenght; i++){
        list2->appendToTail(arr2[i]);
    }

    list1->print();
    list2->print();

    generateDuplicateNodeDataFound(list1, list2, list_found_duplicates);
    list_found_duplicates->print();

    delete list1;
    delete list2;
    delete list_found_duplicates;

    cin>> arr1[0];

    return 0;
}
```

Laurent's Friend code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
class Node{
  public:
    Node(int value= 0, Node* nextNode= nullptr);
    void insertAfter(Node* newPtr);
    Node* getNext();
    int getValue();
  private:
    int val;
    Node* nextNodePtr;
};
Node::Node(int value, Node* nextNode){
  this->val= value;
  this->nextNodePtr= nextNode;
}
void Node::insertAfter(Node* newPtr){
  Node* tempPtr = nullptr;
  tempPtr= this->nextNodePtr;
  this->nextNodePtr = newPtr;
  newPtr->nextNodePtr =tempPtr;
}
Node* Node::getNext(){
  return nextNodePtr;
}
int Node::getValue(){
  return this->val;
}

bool search(int Key, Node* temp){
  bool found= false;
  if(temp!= nullptr){
    while(Key != temp->getValue()){
      temp= temp->getNext();
      cout<<Key<<" , "<<temp->getValue()<<endl;
      if(temp->getNext() == 0){
        found= false;
        break;
      }
    }
    if(Key==temp->getValue()){
      found=true;
    }
  }
  return found;
}
//tries to intersect
void intersect(Node* start1, Node* start2,Node* node){
  Node* node1 = start1;
  Node* node2 = start2;
  Node* temp= nullptr;
  cout<<"\n!i am here!\n";
  while(node1!=nullptr){
    cout<<"\n"<<node1->getValue()<<"\n";
    cout<<"\n!i am here now!\n";
    if (search(node1->getValue(), node2)){
      node->insertAfter(node1); 
      node=node->getNext();
    }
    node1= node1->getNext();

  }

}
// prints liked list
void printList(Node* start){

  while(start->getNext()!= nullptr){
    cout<<start->getValue()<<" ";
    start= start->getNext();
  }
  cout<<start->getValue();
  cout<<endl<<endl;
}
//merging algorithm 
void merge(Node* start,Node* end, Node* node){
  cout<<start->getValue()<<" ";
  while(start->getNext()!= nullptr){
    cout<<start->getValue()<<" ";
    node->insertAfter(start);
    node= node->getNext();
    start= start->getNext();
  }
  while(end->getNext()!=nullptr){
    cout<<start->getValue()<<" ";
    node->insertAfter(end);
    end= end->getNext();
  }
}


int main() {
  Node* new1= nullptr;
  Node* new2= nullptr;
  Node* new3= nullptr;
  int arr[]={2,5,7,9,0,2};
  new1 = new Node(arr[0]);
  new3= new1;
  for(int i=1; i<6;i++){
    new2 = new Node(arr[i]);
    new3->insertAfter(new2);
    new3=new2;
  }
  printList(new1);
  cout<<endl;
  Node* newst = nullptr;
  new2= nullptr;
  new3= nullptr;
  int arr1[]={9,78,3,2,5,9};
  newst = new Node(arr1[0]);
  new3= newst;
  for(int i=1; i<6;i++){
    new2 = new Node(arr1[i]);
    new3->insertAfter(new2);
    new3=new2;
  }

  cout<<endl;

  printList(newst);
  if(search(1,new1)){
    cout<<"ll\n";
  }
  cout<<"\nll\n";
  if(search(7,newst)){
    cout<<"lol\n";
  }
  Node* inter = new Node(0);
  intersect(new1, newst, inter);
  printList(inter);
}
```

Comment: Is your friend aware that you posted their code and allowed you to post it under [CC-BY-SA](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/25/attribution-required/)? By the way, you likely want to add the [tag:comparative-review] tag.

Comment: No, I didn't think it was a big deal because it was for an up coming school assignment. I will ask them and keep and remove the code by their wishes. [EDIT] They don't care.

Comment: Which version of C++ is this targeting? Any? C++98? Or a more modern version, like C++11/14/17? // If this was a solution to an exercise question, it might be helpful to include that question in its original wording. Small details matter!

Comment: Friend's code has two (identical?) `main`s. You may want to remove one.

Comment: The output of those 2 "solutions" are very different. Even if one ignores the rest, the output of the intersection is `{2, 5, 9, 2}` in your code and `{0, 2}` in your friends' code. // Is the repetition of `2` in the result set intended? Why do those two implementation give different results? To me, it seems like the code either isn't working as intended, or there is some context missing why both answers would be correct.

Comment: The most interesting part is handling of duplicates; assuming we have `n` occurences of the same value in first list and `m` in second one: Do you want to have `min(n, m)` occurences in result or just one single?

Answer (score 4):

- Avoid `using namespace std;`. This can easily lead to name clashes. While a recommendation in source files, absolutely no-go in header files(!).
- It's a good idea to encapsulate the linked list into its own class. However, still anybody could modify the nodes in the list unsupervised, in worst case destroing the list or creating memory leaks. So nobody should be able to change the `next` pointer apart from `LinkedList` class. Solution: Make the pointer private and `LinkedList` a friend of `Node`; as then `Node` gets closely coupled to `LinkedList`, it would be more apprpriate to make the former a nested class of the latter.
- Give `Node` class a constructor accepting the value and setting its successor node to nullptr - as your friend did. You don't need accessor functions, remember, you made LinkedList friend (see above). In contrast to your friend, use the constructors initialiser list, though:

  ```
  Node::Node(int data, Node* next)
  : data(data), next(next)
  { }
  ```
- What did you intend with `appendExistingNodesToTail`? It does exactly the same as `appendToTail`, the first parameter is unused and gets overwritten immediately. If you *intended* to append multiple nodes (then second parameter is not needed): Better accept another `LinkedList` as const reference and copy the internal data from.
- In both forementioned functions you forgot to set length to one if the list was empty before. Easiest fix: move `length++` out of the else clause to the very end of the function.
- You have `appendToTail` - for symmetry, I'd name the other function `prependToHead`.
- You did not provide search/find function as your friend did; albeit it was just a helper function for your friend, it still would nicely fit into your linked list's interface.
- You are re-inventing the wheel! While it might be a good *exercise*, once you're done with, switch over to `std::list<int>` (doubly linked) or `std::forward_list<int>` (singly linked).
- Your friend's merge algorithm is broken:

So far for the linked list...

- `intersect` is the better name (describing the same, but much shorter).
- Intersection: Assuming you have lists `{ 7 }` and `{ 7, 7 }`, then your friend's algorithm will output `{ 7 }` while yours will: `{ 7, 7 }`. If you swap arguments, both algorithms will output `{ 7, 7 }`, i. e. your friend's variant is *not* symmetric. Your variant, though, with `{ 7, 7 }` and `{ 7, 7 }` as arguments, will yield `{ 7, 7, 7, 7 }`! To avoid, you'd have to check if the current `head1` element has occured in the list before. But if you do so in the native approach, you'd get an O(n³) algorithm from one that already now is O(n²). So we should really look for better alternatives. If it is fine to modify the lists, you could sort both of them in advance, then finding duplicates is straight forward and O(n). If want to retain original order, you might operate on duplicates instead (possibly copy the data into arrays for faster access and saving memory).
- ... in theory at least. Actually, your friend's `intersect` algorithm is broken: after `node->insertAfter(node1);`, `node1`'s successor is whatever `node`s was before, and the rest of the linked list gets lost (leaking). From a point of view of design, it's not a good idea to change the input lists anyway. Your friend would need to create new nodes as you did.
- Your friend's merge algorithm is broken as well, suffers from same bad usage of `insertAfter` as `intersect` does already. Additionally: Why do we need three pointers? We'd pass two lists, merge them into one single list, and best: return pointer to new head. Your friend's algorithm seemd to try to merge as `x[0], y[0], x[1], y[1], ...`. One could. But what's the benefit from? The lists are not sorted anyway, so one could just as well only *append* one to the other.

My personal assessment: Albeit there are yet a few issues left open, you already did quite a good job on improving the original interface of your friend...

One final issue about your main:

```
LinkedList* list1 = new LinkedList();
// ...
delete list1;
```

It is good that you `delete` what you `new`ed. You can avoid explicit deletion by usage of a smart pointer:

```
std::unique_ptr<LinkedList> list1(new LinkedList());
```

but why `new` at all? Your class is not that big that you might risk to consume up too much of the stack, so just do:

```
LinkedList  list1;
//        ^ no pointer!
```

This will create a variable with scope local to main function and as soon as the scope is left, the object is destroyed automatically (just as with the smart pointer; actually, the smart pointer works exactly the same, `delete`ing the object it points to in its destructor).

Comment: Re "To avoid, you'd advance `head1` as long as it is equal to its predecessor.": IIUC, that still wouldn't prevent `{7, 2, 7}` and `{7}` returning `{7,  7}`. A better way would be to check whether the current value is already in the result list.

Comment: @hoffmale Oh, you're absolutely right... Too much used to *sorted* input! Thanks for the hint!

Comment: @ *'is already in the result list'* - one option. `{ 7, 7 }` and `{ 7, 7 }` would yield { 7 } then, though. Possibly valid, unsuitable, if we *wanted* to get `{ 7, 7 }` instead... Did not thing thoroughly enough about to be 100% sure, but I think this would give an O(n³) algorithm.

Comment: Well, that's why I asked for clarification in my comments on the question. Too much hinges on what the expected output should be. // **Making some assumptions:** If the output order isn't important, one could just sort the input lists in \$\mathcal{O}(n \log n)\$ and then implement your original suggestion for a total complexity of \$\mathcal{O}(n \log n)\$. Still, in that case, there is a better linear algorithm: Insert all items from `list1` into an `std::unordered_set`. Then do a pass over `list2`: For each item, if it is in the set, remove it from the set and add it to the output list.

Comment: @hoffmale The hashing approach is nice (`std::unordered_multiset` would allow for multiple values...). Initial try was to avoid additonal memory usage, so sorting the lists *in place*, but with proposition of the duplicates left that territory anyway. Finally, you are right, we are already too deep in the field of assumptions. Let's see what OP answers...